# OpenCV C++ using cv::UMat instead of cv:Mat and pointers

Tags: c++, opencv, mat

I want to change some code in OpenCV to use cv::UMat instead of cv::Mat to get extra speed with OpenCL/GPU when working with images.

But what I used to access image data directly by pointer doesn't work anymore, e.g:

`cv::Vec3b* imageP = image.ptr<cv::Vec3b>(y)`

where image is a cv::Mat and y is the image line offset, because the Ptr() method doesn't exist for UMat.

What is the correct syntax with a UMat? Is it even possible ?

Comment: If you want to access individual pixels, then you need to convert it back to a `Mat`.

Comment: There is this solution that uses a Mat: umat.getMat(ACCESS_READ).at<uchar>(row, column), but using a pointer to a Mat is way faster! This "at" method with a UMat will be too slow. And the image data is somewhere in ram or sram, so there is surely a way?

Comment: I meant vram not sram

Comment: access to `data` in `cv::Mat` directly if you want faster access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you.
I searched a lot and I understand there is no simple solution, but copying back and forth between Mat and UMat is soooo slow :(